# Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value 1

Tags: xcode, multithreading, error-messaging

if let created = _dictionary[kCREATEDAT] {

```
      createdAt = dateFormatter().date(from: created as! String)! //Fails here 
    }else {

        createdAt = Date()

    }
```

Error message 
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 0):

Thats exactly what you asked for by using the ! operator. Use "if let" or "guard" to check for errors and handle them instead.

```
if let created = _dictionary[kCREATEDAT] as? String, 
   let createdAt = dateFormatter().date(from: created) {
}
```